# Select list required attribute styling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a select list which has the attribute 'required' with the first item set as disabled and selected:

```
<select tabindex='4' id='storeys' name='storeys' required >
    <option selected disabled>Select an option</option> 
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
```

My css is:

```
select{
    border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171);  
    height: 24px;  
    font-size: 16px;
    height:24px;
    width:250px;
    color:grey;
}
option{color: #000;}
option:first-child{color: #ccc;}


select:required{border-right:3px solid red;}

select:valid{border-right: 3px solid green;}
```

Question is how do I make the select list border red when the selected option has no value(ie the disabled option) and green when a value has been selected

I have added fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/czs1w6br/ which also has a text input demonstrating the effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the value property of your first option would be "Select an option", which is a perfectly valid value.

Give the first option an empty `value` attribute:

```
<select tabindex='4' id='storeys' name='storeys' required >
    <option value='' selected disabled>Select an option</option> 
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/czs1w6br/3/)